# What does the %qx format specifier mean

Tags: objective-c, c, hex, format-specifiers

In the following obj-c function, what does the %qx format specifier mean (I would imaging the question also holds for use with printf and co.)

```
+(NSString*)stringForHash:(uint64_t)hash
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qx", hash];
}
```

My guess is that it means print the 64 bits in hex, as opposed to `%x` which would only print 32 bits. I cannot however find a good reference confirming this anywhere. What does `q` stand for? Can it be used in conjunction anything else than `x` in format specifiers?

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the link to apple doc which disappeared (so i'm reposting it because its useful http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: It's a good thing that you're reposting it, but for what I can tell it did *not* disappear ;-)

Comment: ah, mmm. Bug looks like. I still cannot see it, anyway it's in one of the answers now...

Comment: Oh, that's what I meant - I see it in one of the answers. If it was also here, then yes, the author has probably moved it. Nevermind.

Comment: The extra `autorelease` is unnecessary and will likely cause a crash

Comment: @DaveDeLong thanks for pointing it out, not my code... I wander why it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string):

it is a pre-C99 extension meaning

> "q - For integer types, causes printf to expect a 64-bit (quad word) integer argument. Commonly found in BSD platforms"

Answer (score 4):

`q` is quad, same like `ll`.

P.S.: `printf` manpage says "Don't use" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the format speciers from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)